# Find closest item from ALS model using KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, collaborative-filtering, als

I have a dataset like:

```
cid_int   item_id   score
  1         678      0.5
  2         787      0.6
  3         908      0.1
  .          .        .
  .          .        .
```

Now I'm running ALS model on this pyspark dataframe for getting recommendation using Collaborative Filtering.

```
als = ALS(userCol= "cid_int", itemCol= "item_id", ratingCol= "score", rank=5, maxIter=10, seed=0)
model = als.fit(X_train)
```

Now I have question that what does output of `model.userFactors` returns, does it return item embeddings like for m items I'll get all the embeddings?

And if yes can I use `KNN` on these embedding to find the closest items to given item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `model.userFactors` will return embeddings for users. In your case, these will be vectors of dimension 5.

Yes, you can use these embeddings for `KNN` model. If the KNN model will perform poorly, try to increase the `rank` value - this will increase the dimension of the vectors.

Comment: Hi, do you have idea how can I validate this KNN recommendation, like any metric or or any concept I can use to evaluate my CF and KNN

Comment: For the recommendation systems, quite often people use metrics such as: "mean average precision at k", "mean average recall at k", "item coverage".